# Can't make circle dots in Slick Slider

Tags: html, css

Tried to make a slider with dots. I set the same height and width for a dot but somehow on a page it looks like an ellipse, not a circle. 
 For example, I set width: 12px;
height: 12px; and it still says that it's 12x16px. 
But with active dot it works just fine.
Here's my CSS:

```
.slider .slick-dots li.slick-active button{
  background-color: rgb(151, 146, 146);
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: none;
  
}

.slider .slick-dots button{
  font-size: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(151, 146, 146);
}
```

[Here's how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V0KC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `padding: 5px;` it will works.

```
.slider .slick-dots button{
      font-size: 0;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 2px solid rgb(151, 146, 146);
      padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: @Yamobura Then please mark as correct answer to help others.

Comment: Could you add an explanation of why this works - to help others in future.

Comment: Its because of  you added `2px` border, so you have 2 options: add `padding: 5px` or use box-shadow with `border: 0`, like this: `box-shadow: rgb(151 146 146) 0 0 0 2px;`